# how to use ktrain for NER Offline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, offline, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

I have trained my English model following this notebook (https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-06-sequence-tagging.ipynb). I  am able to save my pretrained model and run it with no problem.

However, I need to run it again but OFFLINE and it is not working, I  understand that I need to download the file and do something similar to what is done here.

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/136

However, I  am not able to understand where do  I need to change the settings of ktrain.

I  run this:

```
ktrain.load_predictor('Functions/my_english_nermodel')
```

and this is  the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Functions\NER.py", line 155, in load_bert
    reloaded_predictor= ktrain.load_predictor('Z:/Functions/my_english_nermodel')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ktrain\core.py", line 1316, in load_predictor
    preproc = pickle.load(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ktrain\text\ner\anago\preprocessing.py", line 76, in __setstate__
    if self.te_model is not None: self.activate_transformer(self.te_model, layers=self.te_layers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ktrain\text\ner\anago\preprocessing.py", line 100, in activate_transformer
    self.te = TransformerEmbedding(model_name, layers=layers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ktrain\text\preprocessor.py", line 1095, in __init__
    self.tokenizer = self.tokenizer_type.from_pretrained(model_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 903, in from_pretrained
    return cls._from_pretrained(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 1008, in _from_pretrained
    list(cls.vocab_files_names.values()),
OSError: Model name 'bert-base-uncased' was not found in tokenizers model name list (bert-base-uncased, bert-large-uncased, bert-base-cased, bert-large-cased, bert-base-multilingual-uncased, bert-base-multilingual-cased, bert-base-chinese, bert-base-german-cased, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking, bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad, bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad, bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc, bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased, bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased, bert-base-finnish-cased-v1, bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1, bert-base-dutch-cased). We assumed 'bert-base-dutch-cased' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.txt'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, the [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)-based pretrained models are downloaded to `<home_directory>/.cache/torch/transformers`. For instance, on Linux, this will be `/home/<user_name>/.cache/torch/transformers`.

As indicated in the answer above, to reload the *ktrain* `predictor` on a machine with no internet access (for `ktrain` models that utilize models from `transformers` library), you'll need copy the model files in that folder to the same location on the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution when ktrain is run with an internet connection it creates a folder:
'''
C:\Users\lemolina.cache\torch\transformers
'''
I  needed to copy the same folder in the machine that  does not have access to the internet